# Format cells based on current value and another one

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

[Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18vbFoOacJwEC-aMW060LGXs4_XlJxg236DW_K7bzGDE/edit?pli=1#gid=227399593) regarding this question.

I have a set of sheets where each person must use a drop down box to select a house they would like to view. We can easily add a house to the list by inserting the address, and a URL into the "houses" sheet and it will be shown in the dropdown list and the results table.

Everything works so far, but if a house becomes unavailable, I want to mark it unavailable on the "houses" sheet, and then all occurrences of that specific house in the dropdown cells and results section should have a red background.

I could use conditional formatting, but this would require me to apply a different formula to each cell and that wouldn't be practical.

Comment: @pnuts it's now a google sheet, sorry for any confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I regret not elegant but I think your layout is not well suited to Google Sheets' strengths. The best I can suggest is in say J2 of sheet Choices:

```
=vlookup(B2,Houses!$A:$C,3,0)
```

copied down to J30 and J2:J9 copied across to ColumnN. Then select Choices ColumnsB:F and  Format - Conditional formatting..., Custom formula is and:

```
=J1="No"
```

with formatting of red background <kbd>Done</kbd>.

You might want to hide columns J:N.

Answer (score -2):

You should just use conditional formatting.

Step 1: Select Cell B2, go to conditional formatting and create a new rule, "Use a formula to determine which cells to format".

Step 2: Use the following formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,Houses!$A$3:$C$42,3,FALSE)="No"
```

Note: This B2 value since it isn't using $, moves dynamically depending on what cells your formula is applied to. The VLOOKUP looks up the B2 value in the depicted range and returns the 'Available' column (column 3 on the Houses sheet). We're matching on "No" specifically, I believe its case sensitive so watch out for that caveat.

Step 3: Set your format to Red.

Step 4: Make sure your 'Applies to' box is pointed to the following range:

```
=$B$2:$F$9
```

Personally I hate hard coded ranges like these, you should look into dynamic named ranges. That way you can just reference a named range instead of the A3:C42 range for both your Data Validation dropdown as well as these formulas.